# Best way to strip dangerous html tag, mysql injections, and preserve 'good' tags in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, strip, strip-tags

I'm looking for the best way to filter input html text from a webpage, and filter it preserving text formatting, and stripping let's say  tags and other dangerous tags, and still preventing mysql injections.

example:

INPUT

```
<p>I'm new here and i dont know much about php programming</p>
<a href='maliciousWebsite.com'>Click here!</a>
'MYSQL INSTRUCTIONS TO GET THE WHOLE DB
```

OUTPUT

```
<p>I'm new here and i dont know much about php programming</p>
```

Thanks everyone,

Comment: there is nothing like best way ... may be one way is better than other

Comment: i dont think any need to think about security first while we dont know general functionality of any programming language ...

Comment: It's always good to think about security... but indeed before having security issues, you need a viable online product :-)

Answer (score 2):

Make use of `strip_tags()` with the `allowable` tags parameter to allow the neccessary contents which you really want to insert into your table.

For displaying purpose just make use of `htmlspecialchars()` or `htmlentites()`

```
$yourHTMLdata = '<p>I'm new here and i dont know much about php programming</p>
<a href='maliciousWebsite.com'>Click here!</a>
'MYSQL INSTRUCTIONS TO GET THE WHOLE DB';

echo htmlentites($yourHTMLdata);
```

Even the `<script>` tags wont be affected and you won't be XSS'ed